# psd condition for matrix completion

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, convex-optimization, compressed-sensing, matrix-completion

The **nuclear norm** minimization for the matrix completion problem is given by

\begin{align}
\textrm{minimize }  \quad &\|X\|_{*}\\
\textrm{subject to } \quad & X_{ij}=M_{ij} \quad  \forall (i,j)\in \Omega
\end{align}

where $\Omega$ is the set of randomly sampled entries. There are results that show that one can recover the underlying matrix $M$ with high probability given "enough" measurements (e.g., see Theorem 1.1 of Candes and Recht, 2008 [paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/MatrixCompletion.pdf)).

Let the underlying matrix $M$ be positive semidefinite.

1. Without putting any condition on the optimization problem, simply considering the minimization problem above, is it expected that one would recover a positive definite matrix?
2. If the question for $(1)$ is negative, are there recent results that show the positive definite completion and characterize the number of samples, successful recovery rate,...

Thank you for hints, directions or suggestions.

Comment: $\mathrm X$ does not even need to be square, does it? I suspect you are interested in the **positive semidefinite matrix completion** problem. You may want to take a look at Monique Laurent's papers on that. Here's one of them: [Complexity of the positive semidefinite matrix completion problem with a rank constraint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6602)

Comment: If $\mathrm X$ is square, symmetric and PSD, then minimizing the nuclear norm is equivalent to minimizing the trace. Take a look at Emmanuel Candès's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJx8LlNu6QE).

Comment: Dear Rodrigo, thank you for the links esp. the talk by Candes. I appreciate it.

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.